# How interpret the notation $f:\{0,\dots, N-1\} \rightarrow \{0,\dots, N-1\}$, $N$ is a number of the form $2^n$?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, notation, boolean-algebra

I need help how to interpret the following notation for $f$:

> Zeroes and ones form a binary number which can be converted to
>   decimal notation. Thus, we may think of the computer as calculating a function
>   $$
> f:\{0,\dots, N-1\} \rightarrow \{0,\dots, N-1\}, 
> $$
>   where $N$ is a number of the form $2^n$, and $n$ is the number of bits in the computer memory. In this description, $f$ must be a function because the computer cannot generate two or more different outputs from the same input. We assume without loss of generality that the domain and codomain of $f$ are of the same size. In other words, we assume that both the input and the output of the computer have the same number of bits.

***Update:***

*I understand the function notation 
\begin{align}
f&:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R_+ \\
x& \mapsto f(x)
\end{align}
so if $x\in \mathbb R$ we have $f(x)\in\mathbb R_+$.
So far so good.*

*However I don't follow the meaning (mapping) of $\{0, \dots, N-1\}$ in this case.*

**Attempt:**

Say I have the decimal number $5$, so $N= 5$. I guess "of the form $2^n$" means a binary number, i.e. $5_{10}=(0101)_2$ and thus $n=4$. So I have the function
$$
f: \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\} \rightarrow \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}
$$

Is this correct?

Or is the domain and codomain of $f$ a binary number?  I.e. **no commas in the sets**
$$
f: \{0101\} \rightarrow \{0101\}
$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the notation $f\colon A\to B$ mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347367/what-does-the-notation-f-colon-a-to-b-mean)

Comment: Hi @MarkS! No actually, I understand the notation $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, however I don't grasp $\{0, \dots, N-1\}$ in this specific case.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3624705/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/124092/755.    Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 3):

Just as in "$\{0,1,2,3,4\}$", the commas in "$\{0,\ldots,N-1\}$" separate elements of a set. The "$\ldots$" suggests filling in all the elements between $0$ and $N-1$. This set and [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) notation is standard and separate from any discussion of binary or computers.

For example, if $n$ is $3$, so that $N=2^3=8$ and $N-1=7$, we have $\{0,\ldots,N-1\}=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$.

There are *many* functions $f:\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}\to\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$. For example, one of those functions sends each of $0,2,4,6$ to $5$, and sends $1$ and $3$ to $6$, and sends $5$ to $3$, and sends $7$ to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Each decimal number $x\in\{0,1,\ldots,2^n-1\}$ can be represented as
$$x = x_02^0 + x_12^1 + x_22^2 +\ldots+ x_{n-1}2^{n-1},$$ 
where $x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1}\in\{0,1\}$.
In this way, $x$ can be represented in binary format $x_{n-1}\ldots x_0$ with most significant position at front.